# Find $\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{x+j\pi}$ for $j$ a natural number.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Im having trouble evaluating the definite integral of
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{x+j\pi}$$
for an arbitrary positive integer $j$. Does anyone have any ideas on how to compute this definite integral?

Comment: Why repost about the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814132/want-to-find-definite-integral-to-help-show-that-frac-sinxx-notin-l10?noredirect=1#comment10242905_4814132)?

Comment: i wanted to rewrite a more direct question in the part where i am struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let : $$t = x+j\pi$$
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{x+j\pi}dx
 = \int_{j\pi}^{\pi(j+1)}\frac{\sin(t-j\pi)}{t} dt = \int_{j\pi}^{\pi(j+1)} \frac{\sin(t)\cos(j\pi)-\sin(j\pi)\cos(t)}{t}dt= \int_{j\pi}^{\pi(j+1)} (-1)^j\frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt $$

we have :
$$\begin{align}\boxed{\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx =Si(x)+c}\end{align}$$

therfore:
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{x+j\pi}dx=(-1)^jSi(j\pi+\pi)-(-1)^jSi(j\pi)=(-1)^j(Si(j\pi+\pi)-Si(j\pi))$$

Comment: @ArielFishbein Sorry. First time tagging.

Comment: Don't be lol @BobDobbs

Answer (score 2):

You have to work with a special function called the 'sine integral', or $\text{Si}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}$. We use the fact that $\sin t = \sin(t + 2k\pi)$ and that $\sin (t + \pi) = - \sin t$. In your case, for $j$ even the integral will be
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{t + j \pi}  = \int_{j\pi}^{(j+1)\pi} \frac{\sin t}{t} = \text{Si}\left((j+1)\pi\right) - \text{Si}(j\pi).
$$
For $j$ odd, the integral will be
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{t + j \pi}  = \int_{j\pi}^{(j+1)\pi} \frac{\sin (t + \pi)}{t} = \int_{j\pi}^{(j+1)\pi} -\frac{\sin t}{t} = - \text{Si}\left((j+1)\pi\right) + \text{Si}(j\pi).
$$
You can summarise the result as
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{t + j \pi}  =  (-1)^j \left(\text{Si}\left((j+1)\pi\right) + \text{Si}(j\pi) \right).
$$
Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral). This is not an elementary function, so there is no simpler way of representing it with basic operations. It is produced as the limit of an infinite sum.

Comment: can you explain the first step?  Something is missing

Comment: @SineoftheTime, I made an error. It's fixed now. The other solution is good.